# Japanese voice for espeak

Tags: command-line, java, espeak

What do I need to download to have espeak speak in Japanese? If I can't do it in espeak, is there a similar program I can run? Anything compatible with java or will run in the terminal will be excellent.

Comment: There are several reasons why there isn't Japanese voices. But! If you want you can use Vocaloids with Wine. The drawbacks? Is a paid application.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah I'm looking for a free program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339421/java-download-text-to-speech-from-google-translate) details how to use google translate to download a mp3 file.
And you can use the mp123 command to play the file.